# mysql> create database test; ERROR 1006 (HY000): Can't create database 'test' (errno: 2)

Tags: mysql

I can't create a database after logging in mysql under my root account. Do I have to make an admin account to do so? Also, for some reason, my StartUp file didn't install (there was an error). I'm not sure if that will affect anything else since mySQL DOES start up when I type "mysql" into my terminal.

Also when I type in

```
mysql> SELECT Host, User FROM mysql.user;
+---------------------+------+
| Host                | User |
+---------------------+------+
| 127.0.0.1           | root |
| ::1                 | root |
| myname-mac.att.net  |      |
| myname-mac.att.net  | root |
| localhost           |      |
| localhost           | root |
+---------------------+------+
```

Which I don't get. I seem to have multiple root users and I don't know what ::1 means.

EDIT: My databases currently look like this.

```
mysql> SHOW DATABASES;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)
```

And it doesn't matter what I type in as my database name. I even tried calling it 'apple'.

Comment: There is, by default, a database already named [`test`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/database-use.html). To view it, try using `SHOW DATABASES;`. Have you tried creating a table with a different name?

Comment: I tried other names. It didn't work. See above edit.

Comment: Try to restart your computer and try it again.

Answer (score 7):

It might be problem with space.
Follow this

1. Check .err logs at `/var/lib/mysql`
2. if the log says something like 
   "[ERROR] Can't start server: can't create PID file: No space left on device"
3. Check /var size by `df -hk /var`
4. if used is 100% , then u have to find the files which is geting filled.
5. find large file in /var by

   ```
   find /var/ -type f -size +100000k -exec ls -lh {} \; | awk '{ print $9 ": " $5 }'
   ```
6. see which file you can delete and then restart the mysql process by
7. `/etc/init.d/mysql restart`

let me know if that worked :)

Answer (score 3):

If you're on macosx and if you've system preference pane installed, that should show a message like

```
the following directory is not owned by _mysql user - "/usr/local/msyql/data"
```

Once you know that path you can do the following:

```
sudo chown -R mysql:mysql /usr/local/mysql/data

sudo chown -R mysql:mysql <path>
```

Comment: do note that you need to create a `data` directory first then do that for some people. in ubuntu, it was /var/lib/mysql/data

Answer (score 2):

You have one root user for several domains. Meaning you can connect and run queries on that database FROM the specified domains.

If you want to only show one, give it '%' for the domain and remove all others, although that is not advised. Save the root user for run rights only from localhost, and create limited users for running queries from outside.

As for test database error, it happens on fresh installs. Just reboot the mysql server(stop/start process) or the computer.

Also, make sure you have full rights by doing

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'thedomainyourunfrom/localhost/%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

this will give your root user full rights across all databases in the server

osx manual http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-macosx-excerpt/5.0/en/macosx-installation.html

Comment: sorry I'm new at this. I did GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES; That didn't do anything though. By your recommendation, I guess I'll restart my computer.

Comment: 'root'@'localhost' and 'root'@'127.0.0.1' to make sure everything works fine . Provided you are running the SQL commands locally on the server, that is. Let me know how restart worked.

Comment: So I restarted my computer and now I can't even start mysql. When I type "mysql" into the computer it says ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)

Comment: Edit: I just tried sudo /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe via some other stackoverflow post suggestion and it worked? Is that right?

Comment: according to the installation manual it is a necessary step. Weird, I never thought the OS su would be needed to launch it

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-macosx-excerpt/5.0/en/macosx-installation.html

Answer (score 1):

As an additional resource, you can try two other things:

1. Find out the data folder for your MySQL and 'chown' it so that mysql can write properly to it. For example, if your MySQL's data folder is  `/usr/local/mysql/data/`, you can 'chown' it by typing up the command `chown -R mysql:mysql /usr/local/mysql/data/`
2. If you have just installed your MySQL server, try restarting your computer. Sometimes the installer fails on giving proper file access to the program

I hope that helps!